# C++ Singleton in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, singleton

I'm trying to make a Singleton class in C++ with Xcode. It's a really basic class and I get a linker error that I don't understand. Can any1 help please?

Here is the class header file :

```
#ifndef _NETWORK_H_
#define _NETWORK_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "Module.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * Assume only one network can run at a time 
 * in the program. So make the class a singleton.
 */
class Network {
private:
    static Network* _instance;
    list<Module*> _network;

public:
    static Network* instance();
};

#endif
```

Here is the impl file :

```
#include "Network.h"

Network* Network::instance() {
    if (!_instance)
        _instance = new Network();
    return _instance;
}
```

Here is the compiler error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Network::_instance", referenced from:
      Network::instance() in Network.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare actual storage for `Network::_instance` somewhere.  Likely the impl. file.

Try adding to your impl file:

```
Network *Network::_instance=0;
```

Comment: +1 for setting the instance pointer to 0, checking against uninitialized pointers sets off an alarm in my head.

Comment: @VoDurden: Global data is *always* initialised to zero.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that, thanks. In light of that I'm upvoting your answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to *define* your instance in the implementation file:

```
#include "Network.h"

Network *Network::_instance;
```

The `static Network *_instance;` declaration just says that there exists a `Network::_instance` somewhere. You must provide a single definition somewhere for it to actually exist.

Comment: I wonder how to declare this instance if I don't have header file and implement file, the class is in one file, where should I put the declaration?

Comment: @WindMemory Put the definition somewhere in your source file, outside the class declaration.